# How to Use paintText to set position in image in android?

Tags: android

the canvas is made to set Image and text on it but how to put the text on the bottom center of the image

```
    newCanvas.drawBitmap(bml,0,0,null);
    String captionString =editTextCaption.getText().toString();
    if(captionString !=null) {
    Paint paintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paintText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paintText.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paintText.setTextSize(100);
    paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paintText.setShadowLayer(10f,10f,10f, Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set the Text on the bottom center of the image:

```
newCanvas.drawText(captionString,bml.getWidth()/2f,bml.getHeight(),paintText);
```